# how to load image and menu in one Panel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Currently i am making one application in which menu is there but when i am trying to add image then it gives a error when i am using `paintComponent()` method.

following is my code:

```
public class ImageActivity extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private BufferedImage image;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ImageActivity frame = new ImageActivity();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ImageActivity() {

        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/src.jpg"));


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        setTitle("Image Editor");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmLoadImage = new JMenuItem("Load Image");
        mnFile.add(mntmLoadImage);

        JMenuItem mntmSaveImage = new JMenuItem("Save Image");
        mnFile.add(mntmSaveImage);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        mnFile.add(separator);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);

        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenuItem mntmIncreaseBright = new JMenuItem("Increase Bright");
        mnEdit.add(mntmIncreaseBright);

        JMenuItem mntmDecreaseBright = new JMenuItem("Decrease Bright");
        mnEdit.add(mntmDecreaseBright);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        mnEdit.add(separator_1);

        JMenuItem mntmRestoreImage = new JMenuItem("Restore Image");
        mnEdit.add(mntmRestoreImage);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);

        JMenuItem mntmHelpCtrl = new JMenuItem("Help ctrl + K");
        mnHelp.add(mntmHelpCtrl);

        JMenuItem mntmAboutImageEditor = new JMenuItem("About Image Editor");
        mnHelp.add(mntmAboutImageEditor);

        JSeparator separator_2 = new JSeparator();
        mnHelp.add(separator_2);

        JMenuItem mntmAboutCompany = new JMenuItem("About Company");
        mnHelp.add(mntmAboutCompany);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        protected  void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);             
        } 

    }

}
```

anyone can guide me that where m i wrong ??

> i m beginner in java so please assist me.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it shows error that void in invalid return type for paintComponent().

Answer (score 1):

> where m i wrong ??

1. Overriding `JFrame`
2. Trying to create a method within a method
3. Assuming that `JFrame` has a `paintComponent` method.

Unless you have a really special need, use a `JLabel` instead to render images

**Updated**

You could instead, trying something more like...

```
contentPane = new JPanel() {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);             
    } 
}
```

**Updated**

You are ignoring the exception that might be thrown by `ImageIO`, which will tell you if the image failed to load

```
 try
 {
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/src.jpg"));
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: the intention was "method"!

Comment: @imulsion Fat fingers and slightly out of aligned keyboard make for bad typing - I'm a programmer, what do you expect ;)

Comment: Check update, make sure you are not ignoring the `Exception` and that the image is actually being loaded

Comment: Two things come to mind.  Either the path should be `images/src.jpg` or you should be using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/src.jpg"))` instead